# 'Not a private Key' error when trying to convert pem to ppk

Tags: ssh, private, putty, public

I'm trying to access my friend's AWS server via ssh. He's given me the host name as well as a pem file. I'm relatively new to this and am trying to use putty to connect to the login. For him on Windows, he uses the PuttyGen to convert his pem files into ppk files. But on Ubuntu I couldn't find a GUI version for puttygen and tried looking up on converting the pem file to a ppk file but with no luck. Tried converting it using

```
puttygen myFile.pem -o newFile.ppk
```

but get an error

```
puttygen: unable to load file `myFile.pem': not a private key
```

I've tried the same command with the -O private option at the end but with no luck either. Even if I try to use ssh with the -i option with the pem file itself, it asks me for a passphrase which I don't know and my friend says there is no passphrase.

My friend gave me his ppk file which I tried to use with Putty but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell if the private key is encrypted or not by printing the public key

**encrypted key:**

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/test_key_with_passphrase
Enter passphrase: 
ssh-rsa   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC5kB+0TPMDH/OQ6t/ps67DDJvZzAFF4QyqTYFS3K86bmEz5DeIBtB8kgi3a7ecft6/ooeq+WnuyGvInwNY9GqrO3WDbP4joAqAc6waolEIcs8Nb6iNK+Zhv3O0BfAeXnb5aAztGFfzoBKz6MFGw6Haod3BkZiC40/owG11rjwvb7p4mlHsGrjPpBOGMZ66zPBPuEoFDcCDUnpgh9tNww4Wrzcp+jgZM1MP5ylRCiQE/ssgu3G0zZ3H+5YwRN/XNChomXW74W/yBnp5gAqJZNhiuxTaZBDANXAyiqwrysfzYFgzvTDfyf03aysPAMWkWucmMHxnHz5C649ikSLAOK+h
```

**unencrypted key:**

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/test_key_in_the_clear.pem
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCxNX8DHatQQYw05PHcEvwHwKaqDvZUQWG23uUxQSxEiq1crf2j9dPCfzigKcPxIYarTIJ6yvdP6Kl/ONb+OKM7j6dd8ljO5LOs7dsgA5Tr2gaWyjrjmg767VCN2PB6BJZ9xz+p3SGTdFWtUXYtaEPAGocRx09N9kofpecRbRMlnbfHotyK8canGYzzRfimzk/uDAC/CcpeG3YLphj7zhpRaXhgdu/FKcdiTryqgktlZreJEbefeq3CEBM9kmxvr2uDc+QSVnhbcdutTJ4u4DEop0ZuTREZ2tH2HoAVruiJQ7Nd/VP8jz3SD5ySFBzPGiPcNMQ2mOP0cffm55+3CTwT
```

Once you've worked that out, then ssh with -i to get on to the server, if you are using ubuntu there's no need to bother with putty.

**EDIT**
Here's what a pem file would normally look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,0E109A1A0F7582B0D8B5AAAFDAB18C2A
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If the file doesn't look like that then you dont have a pem file.

Comment: That's the thing. My friend says that there is no passphrase! But when I un the above command, it asks me for a passphrase.

Comment: Is it actually a pem file? I think your file may be corrupted somehow. usually a pem file looks like this: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,0E109A1A0F7582B0D8B5AAAFDAB18C2A
 .... `

Comment: Darn it. You're right. My file got corrupted and hence all the problems... :|
So simple using ssh -i key.pem login worked for me. Thanks anyway :D